# Issue with the dimensions of a simple 2x2 matrix

Tags: matrix

At the end of a huge calculation, I am expecting a 2x2 matrix, but instead I get something like this `X = {{{{x11}}, {{x12}}}, {{{x21}}, {{x22}}}}; When I check its dimension, *Mathematica* says [2,2,1,1].

My question: How can I convert `X` into a 2x2 matrix with correct dimensions?

Comment: Are you working with vectors and using `{{a, b}}` for a row vector instead of just using `{a, b}`?

Answer (score 4):

another option

```
X = {{{{x11}}, {{x12}}}, {{{x21}}, {{x22}}}};
X = ArrayFlatten[X]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
X = {{{{x11}}, {{x12}}}, {{{x21}}, {{x22}}}};
Partition[Flatten[X], 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
X = {{{{x11}}, {{x12}}}, {{{x21}}, {{x22}}}};
ArrayReshape[X, {2, 2}]
(* {{x11, x12}, {x21, x22}} *)
```